# iOS11.2 UIKeyboard forcing the UIViewController to scroll to make room for the keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

When I updated to Xcode 9.2 last night, I found that the keyboard was forcing the `UIViewController` to scroll to make room for itself.

[image: image 1]

I put a `UITextView` at the bottom of the root view. When the keyboard appears, it  forces the `UIViewController` to scroll to make room.

[image: image 2]

Before Xcode 9.2, the keyboard was placed on top of the text object and the `UIViewController` did not move.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: will ,It's my fault。after run pod install , a new pod named IQKeyboardManage which I don't know it has been installed.

Answer (score 0):

will ,It's my fault。after run pod install , a new pod named IQKeyboardManage which I don't know it has been installed.